# TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable - NLTK book with Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am repeaing examples from NLTK book "Natural Language Processing with Python" in Python console. (i use Pycharm 2.7.2, Windows 7, Python 3.3.2). I am new to Python and dont know how to fix. I downloaded today latest NLTK from https://github.com/nltk/nltk but no matter.

On page 39 it throws an error: TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

```
>>> fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
>>> fdist1
Out[7]: <FreqDist with 19317 samples and 260819 outcomes>
>>> vocabulary1 = fdist1.keys()
>>> vocabulary1[:50]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2732, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-9-30d7de8cfb37>", line 1, in <module>
    vocabulary1[:50]
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output should be:

```
>>> vocabulary1[:50] 
[',', 'the', '.', 'of', 'and', 'a', 'to', ';', 'in', 'that', "'", '-',
'his', 'it', 'I', 's', 'is', 'he', 'with', 'was', 'as', '"', 'all', 'for',
'this', '!', 'at', 'by', 'but', 'not', '--', 'him', 'from', 'be', 'on',
'so', 'whale', 'one', 'you', 'had', 'have', 'there', 'But', 'or', 'were',
'now', 'which', '?', 'me', 'like']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the interface changed and you need to do `list(vocabulary1)[:50]` or something like that.
see `help(map)`

```
>>> a=lambda x: x+2
>>> b = map(a, [1,2,3])
>>> b[0:2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
>>> list(b)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Big thanx! list(vocabulary1)[:50] - is working! The more general question i am interested: is there any docs on changes in syntax for Python 3 from Python 2 for NLTK? I afraid i will face other problems soon

Comment: There are always change logs like http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html, google. Dunno about ntlk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Use `vocabulary1 = list(fdist1)`. You can then access the 50 most frequent words by `vocabulary1[:50]`.